# Count the number of occurrences of text using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table with the following fields:

```
-------------------
Customer      Model 
-------------------
A             abc
B             abc|xyz
C             xyz|cde
```

How do I count the number of occurrences of abc, xyz, and cde? Thanks!

Comment: You should seriously give consideration to _changing_ your data model, such that each pipe-delimited model is on its own row.  Avoid storing `|` separated data.

Answer (score 0):

**SUBSTRING_INDEX** is your friend.
You can compare it with a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( Model , "|", 1) =  "xyz" OR
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( Model , "|", -1) = "xyz";
```